# How do you save an Nhibernate entity with a joined field

Tags: nhibernate

I have a User table which has a foreign key to the UserType table.  I created a User object with a Type property that is mapped as a join to the UserType table.  Is there a way to insert a new User without inserting a new UserType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of join is not supported, join is designed for 1 to 1 mappings.  This was answered on the NH users list: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhusers/U6wIDLZRJZg/discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if the Type property is a new type that is not in the database (i.e. has no id yet) it will be inserted and given a new id.  If the type was pulled out of the database, the user will be inserted and the id of the existing type will be used.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too, but Nhibernate is not tracking Types because they are not entities...  Do I have to have both a reference and a join so I can load the Type?

Answer (score 0):

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-join

> Using the element, it is possible to map properties of one class to
>   several tables, when there's a 1-to-1 relationship between the tables.

Meaning, each User will have a row in both tables.

Comment: I don't want to have a UserType entity at all, I am using <join> to include those columns in my User entity.

Comment: My bad, I misinterpreted your question.